# No me deja renderizar en android Studio 4.0.1

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Ya intenté instalar todas las dependencias e instalé y desinstalé el complemento Google SceneForm Tools (Beta) y no he podido implementar la realidad aumentada, procedí a instalar Android Studio 3.6.3 y aún seguía generando el mismo error donde no me permitió usar el complemento SceneForm de Google Scene Tools, también procedí a cambiar la versión de dependencia **com.google.ar.sceneform.ux: sceneform-ux: 1.15.0** de **buil.gradle (app )** y todavía no me deja, realmente no sé qué estoy haciendo mal, pero no puedo convertir un archivo .OBJ a un archivo .sfb usando **Importar SceneForm activo**
Al momento de renderizar arroja el siguiente error, no he podido solucionarlo, como mencioné antes, procedí a descargar diferentes versiones de Android Studio y de igual forma cambiar la versión de las dependencias y aun así no puedo hacer que funcione. El error que arroja es el siguiente:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.GradleUtil.getGradleBuildFilePath(Ljava/io/File;)Ljava/io/File;
at com.google.ar.sceneform.plugin.actions.ui.GenerateSfbModel.handleFinished(GenerateSfbModel.java:444)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizard.handleFinished(ModelWizard.java:402)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizard.goForward(ModelWizard.java:330)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizardDialog$FinishAction.doAction(ModelWizardDialog.java:313)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper$DialogWrapperAction.actionPerformed(DialogWrapper.java:1834)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6550)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3325)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6315)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4899)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:766)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:739)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:736)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:908)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:846)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:778)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:424)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:698)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:423)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1077)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:708)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:433)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.doShow(DialogWrapper.java:1698)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1657)
at com.google.ar.sceneform.plugin.actions.NewRenderableAction.actionPerformed(NewRenderableAction.java:49)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:298)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:315)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:293)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:263)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:77)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:282)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:110)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:83)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$submitTransaction$1(TransactionGuardImpl.java:107)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:116)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuard.submitTransaction(TransactionGuard.java:121)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:110)
at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:517)
at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:36)
at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:539)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6550)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3325)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6315)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4899)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:766)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:739)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:736)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:908)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:846)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:778)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:424)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:698)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:423)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Que ruta le estas dando de salida?  Donde se guarda el fichero.sfb?